# Better way to make a overlay-image-map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

My objective is to have an image on the screen, and as the user mouses over various polygons they will get a blue-ish overlay over the polygon they are mousing over.

Take this image as an example:

[image]

I envision writing code like this:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" usemap="#polymap">
<img id="StarOverlay" src="StarOverlay.png" style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:59px;display:none;"/>

<map name="polymap">
    <area id="star" shape="poly" coords="0,0,82,126"  alt="Star">
    <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3"  alt="Circle">
    <area shape="Rectangle" coords="124,58,8"  alt="Square">
    <area shape="Rectangle" coords="124,58,8"  alt="Square">
</map>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#star').hover(function () {
        $('#StarOverlay').show();
    }, function () {
        $('#StarOverlay').hide();
    });
});
```

However, I will need to make very detailed overlays for each and take very special care with the mappings.  I need to do 15 images with over 40 mappings on each one, so this will be very time consuming (I estimate it will take me a month or better).

Is there a better way using say HTML5? or any other HTML features to accomplish this without having to build these maps and image overlays in photoshop?

Comment: You can refer to https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ and create various shapes using css

Comment: Good idea, I should be clear though.  I will not always have perfect geometric shapes.  Is there a way to define a poly with points?

Comment: I'd say you're better of with SVG - both when it comes to browser support, and ease of use (from the developer perspective.) And maybe even usability-wise, because you can use put links directly into it, https://www.w3.org/wiki/SVG_Links

Comment: Could you please make a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And include the actual src for working images as well?

Comment: @CBroe I looked into SVG a few hours after I wrote this and it certainly does look like the best way to go.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @zer00ne sorry, this question was theoretical on how to go about doing something.  There was nothing "broken" or not working about what I was trying to do, I'm certain that with a couple of months of work I could have gotten it to work great with image maps, so I saw no reason to include a working code example since I didn't want to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you're better off with SVG *[instead of CSS shapes]* - both when it comes to browser support, and ease of use (from the developer perspective.) And maybe even usability-wise, because you can put links directly into it (see f.e. https://www.w3.org/wiki/SVG_Links)

Hover effects could be handled directly inside SVG as well, as long as you embed it via the `svg` element, so that it can easily be controlled from within the main document's stylesheet.

Getting the shapes to start with should be possible using any halfway decent graphics program/editor that can handle vector graphics/SVG, like inkscape or illustrator. Those tend to include a lot of bloat into their saved SVG files though, so you might want to minify/shrink your SVG before putting it onto the web - https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ is an easy to use online tool for that (for more frequent use you could look at the command line tool it's based on.)